# Sci-Fi/Fantasy/Erotic book/ebook that was about a human female empath

Tags: story-identification, books

A human female empath gets kidnapped(?) and taken to another planet to be the personal empath to its leader(?).

It does take place in the future obviously and I remember that when she gets touched, she passes out because she gets overwhelmed with emotions.

I remember reading an excerpt maybe about 10yrs ago..  I believe the title was "My Empath", but I can't remember anything else.

Comment: Haven't found it, but http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=empath&type=Fiction+Titles might be handy for you to browse through.

Comment: Echoes of [In Conquest Born](https://www.csfriedman.com/in-conquest-born/), but I don't think that's it.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Captured Desire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43895764-captured-desire) by Tasha Winters, but that was published in 2019.

Comment: Or [Coldhearted Assassin](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/51869523-coldhearted-assassin), but again Goodreads gives 2019 as the publication date.